# PHP echo renders: ??? instead of šžćčš

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, echo, utf

I have a weard problem. I have two seperate files, with absolutely same code, one with problem, one without.

code:

```
<?php

$kll="šžćčš";

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<!-- Meta Tags -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />

<!-- END head -->
</head>
<!-- BEGIN body -->

<body>

<?php echo $kll; ?>

</body>
```

Now, when rendered it should output simple result as: šžćčš, but in one file it doesnt, it outputs: �����

What bugs me is that the code is absolutely the same for both files.
You can check it out: 
http://www.husibegovic.com/tt.php (bad one)
http://www.husibegovic.com/cc.php (good one)

Any help please?
Thank you

Comment: You need to **save the file with UTF-8 extension** for this to work. To modify the file to make it UTF-8, try adding UTF-8 BOM: `file_put_contents($yourFile, "\xEF\xBB\xBF". file_get_contents($yourFile));`.

Comment: You saved your file with a wrong charset then.

Comment: +1 @mario Comparing the files should reveal if this is indeed the case. On Unix, try `cmp` or `diff`.

Comment: absolutelly same code, I did copy paste, from first to last line, freaking out here :D